# How to restore certain tables from a BAK file sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a migration project where I need to do some ETL on a snapshot of a database. IT has created a secure .bak file of the requested db and I need to restore it on a non-prod environment before using the ETL script. I'm looking for the cheapest way to do it. At the moment I have a VM with 2TB but seems that this isn't sufficient to restore. I only need a few tables from the backup though. Is there a way to restore only the tables I need? I've seen some old threads that stated this isn't possible but hopefully by now, this has been added as a feature.

Kind Regards,
Andrei

Comment: Backups are all or nothing. You can't partially restore a database. If you want to migrate some objects and data from a database, a backup is the wrong solution.

Comment: There is a request for such not existing functionality: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/e4c0c9e0-6425-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

Answer (score 4):

For SQL Server, the atomic unit of Backup and Restore is a Database, you cannot backup nor restore anything smaller than that(*).

Therefore, to restore a table you must restore the entire database (to say a duplicate database) then copy the table that you want out of that database.

(* -- well yes, I suppose you could backup a log or an individual file or just changes, etc.  But you cannot really restore these usefully in isolation)